# How to shut down replica set in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I use ubuntu.

I start three mongod replica set as follows:

```
$ mongod --replSet setname --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27017 --smallfiles --fork
$ mongod --replSet setname --logpath "2.log" --dbpath /data/rs2 --port 27018 --smallfiles --fork
$ mongod --replSet setname --logpath "3.log" --dbpath /data/rs3 --port 27019 --smallfiles --fork
```

How can I shut them down?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run the following commands from the Unix shell:

```
mongo --port 27017 --eval 'db.adminCommand("shutdown")'
mongo --port 27018 --eval 'db.adminCommand("shutdown")'
mongo --port 27019 --eval 'db.adminCommand("shutdown")'
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't think the accepted answer is correct. After some googling, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/eYP8HQKPzfk) in mongodb-user group to be the best answer.

> To shutdown:
>   - Run `db.runCommand({ replSetFreeze: numOfSeconds })` on secondaries to 
>   prevent from promoting to primary
>   - Run `rs.stepDown(seconds)` on the primary; it will check to make sure 
>   at least one of the secondaries is sufficiently caught up to oplog 
>   before stepping down. Choose a reasonably long wait time.
>   - Once everything is a secondary, `db.shutdownServer()` on everything
>
> To start up:
>   - Run `rs.freeze(seconds)` on both secondaries with a lengthy timeout (say, 
>   1-2 minutes)
>   - Bring up primary
>   - Use stepDown to fix in case a secondary somehow becomes primary

Simply shutting down is not enough, you have to prevent secondary nodes from promoting to primary.

Comment: This answer is not fully correct either. step 2 => rs.stepDown(seconds) on the primary; will never succeed because the primary cannot elect other nodes before stepping down as they are 'frozen'. I think you may get an error "No electable secondaries caught up.... "

Answer (score 4):

1) Login to mongo shell on Secondary servers

2) Stop the secondary servers by using below command:

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

2] Go to Linux shell- on secondary servers and type below command:

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

For more information, Please check the below link:

http://www.tutespace.com/2016/03/stopping-and-starting-mongodb.html

Comment: The given link is not available now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ps -ef | grep mongod`, get pids for mongod with port numbers 27017-27019, and kill processes with thats pids.

Comment: `ps -ef` seems to print too much information. How about `ps -e` instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I still think that I should answer this.

Run the following command in the unix shell

`ps -ef | grep mongo`

This would give you a list of pid's (process ids) corresponding to the port `27017`, `27018` and `27019`. You can use the pid's to kill all the members of replicaset

Comment: This is solving the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

```
mongod --port 27017 --shutdown 
mongod --port 27018 --shutdown
mongod --port 27019 --shutdown
```

By the way, if there is any possibility you will use sharding in the future, it would be best to avoid ports 27018 and 27019. Those are default ports for some components of a shard cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB 3.2 on Windows, I am using the following sequence:

```
mongo mongodb://localhost:27019/admin --eval "db.shutdownServer({timeoutSecs: 10})"
mongo mongodb://localhost:27018/admin --eval "db.shutdownServer({timeoutSecs: 10})"
mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/admin --eval "db.shutdownServer({timeoutSecs: 10})"
```

Answer (score 0):

shutdown secondaries first to prevent rollbacks.

```
mongo admin --port <port> --eval "<db.auth if needed>;db.shutdownServer()"
```

source: mongodb university course